# How to make laravel 10 recognize auth()->user() is a User model

Tags: php, laravel

So I want to make Laravel recognize that auth()->user() return is a User model type. to do this I use a hacky trick like below

```
/** @var \App\Models\User */
$user = auth()->user();
```

the code above works and the $user is recognized as the User model type, but the problem is, I have to do this (include code `/** @var \App\Models\User */` ) anytime I have to access auth()->user()

Is there any better way at doing this?

Comment: No other ways except you write your own auth system.

Comment: Comments are comments, and have no effect on how Laravel runs. Your problem, if there is one, isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom function like [Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers) that returns `auth()->user()` with the type `User`.

create a file `MyHelpers.php` and put it for example in `App\Helpers`:

##### MyHelpers.php :

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('getAuthUser')) {
    /**
     * @return \App\Models\User|null
     */
    function getAuthUser() :?\App\Models\User
    {
        /** @var \App\Models\User */
        return auth()->user();
    }
}
```

then add this file to composer to be loaded to your project like other Laravel helpers.

##### composer.json :

```
...
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    // ...
}
...
```

after that run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer update`.

now when you need to get the user :

```
$user = getAuthUser();
if (!$user) {
    //handle when user in null.
    return;
}

// $user will be reconized as \App\Models\User
```